# How to create hosted app that allows clients to extend it as they like

Tags: php, architecture, saas

I have an application in heavy development status that I would like to allow my users/clients to extend as their needs (with limitations in plan and etc.) What approach could I use to enable the deployment of own code in to the application?

The options which I was able to think of are:

- Mapper file in the root of a PHAR archive which says what is what. (Kinda like in java :D)
- Manual Deployment, clients upload their code, which we review and put it where it is supposed to go (Which will result in many unhappy customers, b`cuz it will take time to review the code...)

I was thinking in every aspect I could though of, the DB is separated for each app so not much of a concern, but the code could expose many many things which could destroy the business.

What I am looking is a good approach, fresh point of view, possible bumps along the way and fresh ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a scripting language such as Lua? You can choose what functions are exposed to your clients and so there is little risk because clients will lack the functionality to severely screw up your infrastructure.